# How to establish connection with database

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse, swing

I have created a database in mysql.Now trying to connect the database to the program,but I cant.This is part of my code

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.driver");
con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/hr","abilash","abilash");
System.out.println("connected");
java.sql.Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
System.out.println("Connected  Successfully");
stmt.executeUpdate("insert into emp (Name) values( '"+fnamet.getText()+"') ");
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Item Successfully Added",
"Confirmation",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
```

I am using eclipse and I had already added mysql-connector-java.zip(5.1.25).I dont know Whats the real problem was????Please help

Comment: what the error you are getting?

Comment: No such error.Just its executing catch block

Comment: yes.Without any errors.

Comment: @Abilash Ravichandran check my answer below its correct solution for you

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you missed port number in getconnection()

change

```
con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/hr","abilash","abilash");
```

to

```
con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hr","abilash","abilash");
```

Comment: Ahha, just rememberd using this port once, when I was working with `mysql` :-) +1 for this.